# How do I print custom html in nodes of a certain type using template.php?

Tags: 7, theming

I want to print some custom html inside nodes of a certain type. 
I could use node.tpl.php, but i'd prefer a template.php solution.

THX in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to provide a new variable to your node template file you should implement `hook_preprocess_node()` in your theme and pass it from there:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  if ($vars['node']->type == 'node_type') {
    $vars['extra_html'] = my_function_to_build_html_string();
  }
}
```

Then in your node.tpl.php file you can output that HTML wherever you want like so:

```
<?php if (isset($extra_html)): print $extra_html; endif; ?>
```

If you just want to add some HTML into the normal content of the node, you would do it like this:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  if ($vars['node']->type == 'node_type') {
    $vars['content']['extra_html'] = array(
      '#markup' => my_function_to_build_html_string(),
      '#weight' => -10 // Control the display order of this element
    );
  }
}
```

In either case you'll need to clear Drupal's caches once you've implemented this hook so the theme registry picks it up.

Comment: OK, adding a variable I understood that one. But then i'd have to print the variable inside the node.tpl.php.

I don't want touch the node.tpl.php file. 

I want to inject this content inside the $content variable so the the drupal function: print render($content); just renders the html after all other content. Is this possible?

Comment: @jeroen I just added some more to the answer; the second method will require no changes to the node.tpl.php file

Comment: That's it thx man!!!